# A generator that displays a random post from the instagram

Tags: javascript, instagram

I built a generator that displays a random post from my instagram page. I'm looking for an effective way to insert all posts (ID) into an array, including new ones added, automatically. I know where all the ID is located on the source page of my page, is there a way that it will scan it and enter the array?

```
function random_item(items) {
return items[Math.floor(Math.random()*items.length)];
}

function randomPost(items) {
  items = [
         "BvG2eDOlauV",
         "BvtXgE7lz4U",
         "Bw9L2rzF6iq"
      ];

       return random_item(items);
   }

function getPost() {
  window.open("https://www.instagram.com/p/" + randomPost());
}
```

Comment: Instagram has an API that should let you get access to the ids of your posts. No need to scrub page source. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/user/media#get-media

Comment: @roguenet I want to take only my ID and not my users. I did not find such an option in the API.